# How to simply add a < root> tag to XML file using groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

The xml file is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<first_node>
  <second_node>hai</second_node>
</first_node>
```

My expected output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <first_node>
   <second_node>hai</second_node>
 </first_node>
</root>
```

Comment: Uchiha_itachi, can you please check the solution to see if that helps?

Comment: @Rao Sorry for my late response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve using `StreamingMarkupBuilder`as shown below:

```
def xmlstring = """<?xml version="1.0"?> <first_node>   <second_node>hai</second_node> </first_node>"""
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlstring)
def newXml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
   root {
     mkp.yield xml
   }
}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(newXml)
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/BgjOgX)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT but it's powerful tool if you need only add root tag on start. If you need more than that use XSLT. If you need only use groovy xml dom.
Link for groovy and xslt
https://www.pleus.net/blog/?p=1448